Coroutine is not executed entirely
When trying to test a viewmodel, the  getService is never called
i tried moving the usecase to another function, than is called normally, but or some reason looks like is not even a matter of time, but the coroutine is only executing 2 usecases (??)
im felling so dumb right now
test code :
 @Test
    fun `online validation valid OTP `() = runTest {
        val resultResponse = ResultResponse(resultCode = "OK", resultDescription = "Valid")
        val fakeService = FakeOtpService.getInstance(
            MockRequestInterceptor.ResultCode.SUCCESS,
            statusResult = resultResponse
        )
        val viewModel = getViewModel(context, FakeCourierService.getInstance(), fakeService)
        
        advanceUntilIdle()
        viewModel.onValidateOtp("1234", false)

        assertEquals(OfflineOtp.ValidationInfo.ONLINE_VALID, viewModel.getOtpValidationInfo())

    }

viewmodel:
private fun initViewModel() {
        _state.value = OtpUiModel.Loading
        viewModelScope.launch {
            otpSuccessName = getRefRemoteConfigByKey(RefRemoteConfig.Key.OTP_SUCCESS_NAME.text)?.value ?: ""
           
            otpRequiredClients = getRefRemoteConfigByKey(RefRemoteConfig.Key.OTP_REQUIRED_CLIENTS.text)?.getRemoteConfigAsList()
                ?: emptyList()
           
            getService(services.first())?.let { firstService ->
                firstService.isOtpRequired = RefRemoteConfig.isOtpRequired(firstService, otpRequiredClients)
                service = firstService
                Timber.i("First Service (OTP Fragment) : " + service?.code)
            }
           
             getAppConfigValuesById(RefAppConfigValues.TableCode.OTP_ENCRYPTION_KEY, "OTP Key")?.text?.let {
                 otpEncrtyptonKey = it
            }
            _state.value = OtpUiModel.Default
        }
    }

i have tried almost every solution posted here

Well for starters, your test function doesn't seem to actually invoke initViewModel(). I mean, I don't see any hint in the test code that would lead me to believe it's invoking initViewModel() either explicitly or implicitly.  Perhaps you need to share more code and/or provide a [mcve].
